# How to use the Ternary operator for the (if else-if) statement or use two or more conditions in Solidity?

Tags: conditional-statements, solidity, conditional-operator

I want to do using Ternary Operator in the same condition

```
function fun(uint _value) public pure returns(string memory)
   {
       string memory _return;
       if(_value > 100){
           _return = "Greater than 100";
       }else if(_value < 100){
           _return = "Lower than 100";
       }else{
           _return = "Equal to 100";
       }

       return _return;
   }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow . Just asking, why would you do that ? It seems to me that chaining ternary operators leads to "harder to read" code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Ternary Operator for two or more conditions in Solidity

Here is the answer: -

```
    function fun(uint _value) public pure returns(string memory)
    {
        string memory _return;
        _value > 100 ? _return = "Greater than 100" : _value < 100 ? _return = "Lower than 100" : _return = "Equal to 100";

        return _return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes no sense to use the ternary operator here. While writing contracts we should focus on readability. If you are working in a team, your team members must be able to read and understand your contracts easily. If it is not the case and some malicious code slips in due to a fancy choice of code it can cost you a hell amount of gas for no reason. Unlike web2, it's not easy and quick to debug, fix and deploy small hotfixes. You can use the `Proxy Upgrade Pattern` from `OpenZeppelin` but again it is only meant for future updates on the contract and not mostly to fix petty issues.